# How to Integrate $\int (\tan x)^{1/3}\,dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

How to integrate
$$\int (\tan x)^{1/3}\,dx?$$
Is it substitution or by parts?

Comment: wolfram tells us http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28tanx%29%5E%281%2F3%29+dx

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504548/calculating-int-sqrt3-tanxdx-and-int-sqrt4-tanxdx/504556#504556).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\tan x=u^3\implies x=\arctan(u^3)\implies dx=\frac{3u^2du}{1+u^6}$$

$$\implies\int\sqrt[3]{\tan x}dx=3\int\frac{u^3du}{1+u^6}=\frac32\int \frac{vdv}{1+v^3}(\text{ setting } u^2=v )$$

Now using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),  $$\frac{v}{1+v^3}=\frac A{1+v}+\frac {Bv+C}{1-v+v^2} $$

Multiply with $1+v^3$ and equate the constants & the coefficients of $v,v^2$

Now, $\displaystyle 1-v+v^2=\frac{4v^2-4v+4}4=\frac{(2v-1)^2+3}4$

Using [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution), set $2v-1=\sqrt3\tan\theta$

Comment: Nice solution lab bhattacharjee...

Comment: @juantheron, thanks for your feedback