# integrating square root of tanx

Tags: integration

$\int \sqrt{\tan (x)}dx $
Let $\tan(x)=t^{2}$

then $dx$ will become $\frac{2t}{1+t^{4}}$

Hence $\int \sqrt{\tan (x)}dx =\int\frac{2t}{1+t^4} dt $

But I cannot proceed from this step.

Comment: Use the search function on this site to avoid posting duplicate questions.

Comment: Should it be $\int \frac{2t^2}{1+t^4}dt$?

Comment: Your substitution should give $\int \frac{2 t^2}{1 + t^4} dt$.

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504548/calculating-int-sqrt3-tanxdx-and-int-sqrt4-tanxdx). You can advance by using partial fraction noticing that

> $$ \frac{ 2t^2}{1+t^4} = \frac{1}{t^2+i} + \frac{1}{t^2-i},\quad i=\sqrt{-1} .$$

Comment: The OP has a typo so $u=t^2$ doesn't do the job.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: I advanced based on his calculations. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Substutution is fine, but how do u complete the integration by introducing $i$ ?